# How can I link express routes so that / is the home directory of a sub directory

Tags: node.js, express

I have an app with a home page `'/'`. I also have a couple other ones like `'/contact'` and `'/about'`. Now I want to start adding apps to my site (e.g. /apps/project). I would like a navigable `'/apps'` page that can lead to the other projects etc. Is it possible to have a nest in my `app.js` to be able to say that `'/'` is my `'/apps'` page and that `'/project'` would be under `'apps/project'`. I understand that express has [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) but I dont understand how this works or if this is what I need. Should I have a app.get to all of these-
like ? Or is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
app.get('/apps', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/static/Apps/apps.html'));
});

app.get('/apps/project', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/static/Project/project.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create router in file 'filename.js'

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: ''});
});

router.get('/project', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: ''});
});

module.exports = router;
```

and then use it as router in main file

```
const express = require('express');
const apps = require('./filename');
const app = express();

app.use('/apps', apps);
```